# C programing printing wrong characters in array

Tags: c, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
  int a = 1, b = 0;
  int x1 = 0, v1 = 2, x2 = 5, v2 = 3;
  char x[3] = "YES";
  char y[2] = "NO";
  clrscr();

  while (a < 1000) {
    x1 = x1 + v1;
    x2 = x2 + v2;
    if (x1 == x2) {

      b = b + 1;
      printf("i m in 1");
      printf("%s", x);
      break;
    }
    a++;

  }
  if (b < 1) {
    printf("%s", y);
    printf("i m in 2");
  }

  getch();
}
```

It gives output "noyes i m in 2", but why from where it get "yes"?
If it is not going in 1st block then why it print yes?

Comment: `printf("%s",x);` and `printf("%s",y);` are problematic because `x` and `y` do not have null terminators whereas printf with `%s` expects it. Change `char x[3]="YES"; char y[2]="NO";` to `char x[]="YES"; char y[]="NO";`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the strings `x` and `y` that you have declared are not null-terminated. When your code prints out `NO`, it prints out the characters in the array `x` and keeps on printing until it finds a NULL-byte in memory. On your machine, by happenstance the string `YES` was placed in memory just after `NO`, but when I compile this code on my machine I get `NO???im in 2` - in other words, garbage.

What you must do is declare your strings like so:

```
char x[4]="YES\0";
char y[3]="NO\0";
```

That way, `printf` will know when to stop printing characters.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly have the `\0` in the string - as long as the array is big enough, it will be added

Comment: Better:  `char x[] = "YES";`

Comment: Of course you are right. Your approach is cleaner. I'll leave my answer unchanged, though, because I thought it was important to explain why the strange behaviour happened.